# How do you point your Eclipse and Eclipse projects to a new JRE version in eclipse? (Not using JAVA_HOME)

Tags: java, eclipse

Setting up scenario : I have two version of Java on my system.  A 32 bit version and a 64 bit version. The other version I have is the 64 bit version of Eclipse (Java EE).  The MyEclipse (32 bit version) is pointing to the 32 bit version of the JDK.  I'm now trying to point the Eclipse (32 bit version) at the newly installed JDK 1.6.0_32.  the JAVA_HOME variable is already take by the 64 bit version and thus I can't use this.

Previously this environment and projects in this environment were usinig Java 1.6.0_30.  The places where I've changed the JRE version are in
Preferences->Java->Installed JREs.  In here I've added my new JRE and removed the old one.  What other places might I need to change this?  I'm still getting an error referring to 1.6.0_30 when I start up my Apache Tomcat server.  In specific I get the error 
"The archive:Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_30/lib/tools.jar which is referenced by the classpath, doesn't exist. "

Looking in the class paths of my projects I see the correct 1.6.0_33 version.  Where else might I need to change the classpath?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to Window/Preferences/Server/Runtime Environment, select your server (Apache Tomcat), click Edit. There is the JRE that uses your server, you can change it according to your needs.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

one way to correct this error is :

find tools.jar in jre/lib folder and copy the same in required folder /Java/jdk1.6.0_30/lib/ .