# JRE version of my computer

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

I have two jre in my PC which is running windows 7. When I am running a eclipse project I dont know which version of jre it is calling, so I searched on net for the solution and tried this two things:

1. In cmd typed java --version and it showed me 1.6.
2. In control panel, I went it in java control panel and selected java and it showed me 1.7 enabled.

Now, I am confused and how can I change the jre of the system? I want my eclipse project which is running on tomcat to use a specific jre. But I dont know which jre my system is using.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the properties of the project!

Comment: How do you start the Tomcat? Inside Eclipse or do you run it from Windows? Your application will run in Tomcat's JVM.

Comment: But the jre that i am using in the java build path of the project is not getting executed or used. it uses the system default jre for running project

Comment: @flup I start my tomcat in eclipse

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530811/how-do-you-point-your-eclipse-and-eclipse-projects-to-a-new-jre-version-in-eclip then. You'll have to set the tomcat's JRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check **Windows->Preferences->Java->installed** to check  default JRE that it runs things under.

You may also check property eclipse.vm under the  Help->About Eclipse->Installation Details->Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

choose window preferences in eclipse. Select installed jre and add a jre and select an jre you are going to use.

Answer (score 0):

java -version is what a java app on the system will use by default. What IE uses is determined by the extension (Tools->Manage add-ons) you can see the java plugin there.

You can register any jre vesion you want in eclipse using the window->preferences-> installed JRE's

Comment: But he's running his project on tomcat, not as an applet in the browser.

Comment: For the tomcat, that is the java version in the commandline, you can change this using the path variable. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html 
See there for editing the path on the pc

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse, you can set the Java version by going to `project->properties->java build path->select the jre version and click on edit`.

You can choose the version that you want. Whichever JRE library is displayed in the build path is the version that eclipse is using to compile your code.