# Could not start liferay server

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

I can not start my liferay server due to that error :

```
The JRE could not be found. Please edit the server to change the configured JRE
```

But in my preferences JRE is set :

```
jre1.8.0_131
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131
```

and path to it is correct.

This problem occured when I deleted JRE to check something( cause I've had a problem with portlet deployment ). But the path and variable which is set now is exactly the same, the server do not want to start though.

Should I clean something or add it somwhere else? 
I've got my server configured and I do not want to loose all data.
It's liferay 7

Comment: This resolved my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530811/how-do-you-point-your-eclipse-and-eclipse-projects-to-a-new-jre-version-in-eclip

Comment: How do you start Liferay? form IDE or from the command line. If IDE then @Ashish  suggestion should help. Otherwise, make sure that your JAVA_HOME property is right.

Comment: I did it. 
Finally, I've created a new server. Now it's working. Do not know how to solve problem with JRE